# How can I initialize a date to NSDate?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I want to give, for example, `12/11/2005` in the format of `mm/dd/yyyy`. Can I initialize `12/11/2005` to `NSDate` directly? Any help?

It gives a warning and crashes when I declare it as:

```
NSDate *then = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:02/11/2009  locale:nil];
```

Comment: This method is only for Mac OS X v10.0 and later, it is not available in iOS

Comment: `02/11/2009` is not an NSString. `@"02/11/2009"` is.

Answer (score 16):

What you need to do is something like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *mmddccyy = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
mmddccyy.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
mmddccyy.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy";
NSDate *d = [mmddccyy dateFromString:@"12/11/2005"];
NSLog(@"%@", d);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `+ (id)dateWithNaturalLanguageString:(NSString *)string`

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/dateWithNaturalLanguageString:

Comment: it gives warning...crashes.....when i declare as

NSDate *then = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:02/11/2009  locale:nil];

Comment: You need to pass it an NSString.

NSDate *then = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"02/11/2009" locale:nil];

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be the use of NSCalendar and NSDateComponents, since *+dateWithNaturalLanguageString:* is deprecated.

For example you want a NSDate initialised to 15th of August 2001. This is the code that will work for you:

```
NSCalendar *g = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
comps.year = 2001;
comps.month = 8;
comps.day = 15;

NSDate *myDate = [g dateFromComponents:comps];
```

or another way is:

```
let earliestDate = calendar.dateWithEra(1, year: 2012, month: 1, day: 1, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)
```

to set the earliestDate NSDate to 01/01/2012